# Export users & groups & if they are a member of group

Tags: powershell

I need to do a script that will export me enabled users from specific OU and specific value of attribute Company (with some other attributes) and all groups beginning with name "A_ACC*" and if the user is a member of a group or no.

It should look like this on image. [Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TN9Lo.png)

For now I am working with this:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Company -eq "xxxx"} -SearchBase “yyyyy” -Properties GivenName, Surname, DisplayName, Company, Department, memberof, SamAccountName, PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName | Where {($_.Enabled -eq $True)} | % {
  New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    SamAccountName= $_.SamAccountName
    GivenName = $_.GivenName
    Surname=$_.Surname
    DisplayName = $_.DisplayName
    Company=$_.Company
    Department = $_.Department
    Location = $_.PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName
    Groups = ($_.memberof | Get-ADGroup | Where Name -like "A_ACC*" | Select -ExpandProperty Name) -join ", "
  }
} | Select GivenName, Surname, DisplayName, Company, Department, Location, Groups | Export-Csv -Path 'H:\My Documents\PowerShell_exports\Users_export.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

But unfortunately I do not know how to proceed further to get result I want.

Can you please advise?

Thank you!

Comment: What does your current result look like? And how does it differ from your desired result?

Comment: Hi, thanks for asking, but it is resolved. Daniel helped me with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a list of groups that you are looking for you can enters these into an array (shown below as `$groupsToCheckFor`).  Then add a property to each user object for each group with either true/false value depending on whether the group is found in the user's list of groups from `memberof`

```
$params = @{
    Filter     = { Company -eq 'xxxx' } 
    SearchBase = 'yyyyy' 
    Properties = @(
        'DisplayName' 
        'Company', 
        'Department', 
        'memberof', 
        'PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName'
    )
}

# List groups to check for which will be added as columns
$groupsToCheckFor = 'A_ACC_Group1', 'A_ACC_Group2', 'A_ACC_Group3'

Get-ADUser @params | Where-Object { ($_.Enabled -eq $True) } | ForEach-Object {
    $object = [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
        GivenName      = $_.GivenName
        Surname        = $_.Surname
        DisplayName    = $_.DisplayName
        Company        = $_.Company
        Department     = $_.Department
        SamAccountName = $_.SamAccountName
        Location       = $_.PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName
    }

    $groups = ($_.memberof | Get-ADGroup | Where-Object Name -Like 'A_ACC*' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name) 
    $groupsToCheckFor | ForEach-Object {
        # add property for each group being checked for
        # value is true if group is found in users' groups
        $object | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $_ -NotePropertyValue ($_ -in $groups)
    }

    # output object
    $object

} | Export-Csv -Path 'H:\My Documents\PowerShell_exports\Users_export.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel!
This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: You're welcome.  To keep the properties in order change `New-Object PSObject -Property` to `[pscustomobject][ordered]`.  I have updated this in my answer.

Comment: Okay thanks, I edited my comment because I tried to switch columns in Excel and it is pretty easy. 

Once again, thank you!